# JsonServiceClient ResponseFilter doesn't trigger

Tags: c#, servicestack

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but I can't for the life of me get the `ResponseFilter` to trigger on a `JsonServiceClient` in ServiceStack. The `RequestFilter` triggers every time (I'm sending an API token to my API). Here is a sample console app that shows the `ResponseFilter` never writing to the console.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new JsonServiceClient())
    {
        client.ResponseFilter = httpResponse =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ResponseFilter: StatusCode == " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
        };

        try
        {
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = client.Get("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/me");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception => " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm using the latest ServiceStack v4.0.40.0

Comment: Could you provide more of your working example? One problem I can see here is you are disposing of the `JsonServiceClient` which means it if you are making requests with somewhere in code you haven't provided, you are probably using a different instance.

Comment: @Layoric Thanks for the feedback, however 2 things...(1) this example still fails if I don't dispose of the client and (2) in my full code I'm working on I re-use the client between subsequent calls so it's not getting disposed there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code you have provided, in isolation, looks correct apart from the client being disposed in the using statement.

Once the client is created, an action can be registered on the ResponseFilter as you have shown above.

I've created an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/Layoric/ServiceStackResponseFilterExample) in empty ServiceStack ASP.NET solution with a unit test that shows this filter working.

The main part of the code is very similar to the snippet you provided.

```
bool calledRepsonseFilter = false;
var jsonServiceClient = new JsonServiceClient("http://techstacks.io/");
jsonServiceClient.ResponseFilter = response =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("A response!");
    calledRepsonseFilter = true;
};
var res = jsonServiceClient.Get(new AppOverview());
Assert.That(res.TopTechnologies != null);
Assert.That(calledRepsonseFilter == true);
```

I've given the same answer on the ServiceStack forums, but updated this question with the answer in case it helps others as well.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For future visitors, the issue lays with the fact that `ResponseFilter` does not get fired when exceptions happen (like a 401, which is what I was trying to handle in the filter). Instead, I've started using a custom `JsonServiceClient` and overriding `HandleResponseException`.